# Image segmentation with keras and pretrained pspnet50

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I have a pretrained keras model pspnet50_ad20k and want to get a segmented image out of it. The input is an image in a numpy array in the shape (1, 473, 473, 3) and it returns an array in shape (1, 473, 473, 150), because of the 150 different classes this model predicts.

```
import os
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = "tensorflow"
from keras.models import model_from_json

json_file = open('/data/pspnet50_ade20k.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
# load weights into new model
loaded_model.load_weights("/data/pspnet50_ade20k.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")

# img_array contains img in shape (1, 473, 473, 3)
result = loaded_model.predict(img_array)
# result contains img in shape (1, 473, 473, 150)
```

My question: **How can I get from the resulting array to the segmented image?** I somehow have to color the predicted 150 classes in the image but I don't know how. Can someone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ade20k dataset have 150 classes, that's why your network finally output `(1, 473, 473, 150)`. 150 represents the probability of 150 classes at each pixel location. So you need to change the last layer, usually is a `conv2d(256,classes=150,kernel_size=1)`. Please replace 150 with 50, which is the number of classes you want to predict, and fine-tune your model on your own dataset.

For colorizing prediction, you can do like this,

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
prediction = np.argmax(prediction, axis=3) # get the max prob label
palette = np.loadtxt('path/to/ade20k_colors.txt').astype('uint8')
# The format of `ade20k_colors.txt`
# 120 120 120
# 180 120 120
# 6 230 230
# 80 50 50
# 4 200 3
# ...
color = Image.fromarray(prediction.astype(np.uint8)).convert('P')
color.putpalette(palette)
# color is colorized prediction.
```

Answer (score 0):

json_file = open('/data/pspnet50_ade20k.json', 'r')
model u used is coded in way to predict 50 classes,re-code change the model or
construct your own model to predict how many classes you need.

better use keras to constuct your own model with loaded weights of this :loaded_model.load_weights("/data/pspnet50_ade20k.h5")